# What is the invalidateProperties(), invalidateSize() and invalidateDisplayList() functions did while extending a component in adobe flex/air?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4

What `invalidateProperties()`, `invalidateSize()` and `invalidateDisplayList()` methods are did when extending a component in adobe flex/air ?.

And why these are necessary?

Comment: "are did"? What do you mean? Do you need to implement these somehow, or...? As for why they exist, see the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IInvalidating.html

Comment: are did  = their job in the process of extending a control in flex.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IInvalidating.html), these functions signal flex/flash to call another function before updating and rendering the display list. This "other function" seems to be for validation (and possibly altering the values if they're incorrect). So by calling an invalidate function, you force a recalculation. Or, in other words, a redraw. This removes any left over graphical artifacts.

That's my explanation via the documentation. Perhaps someone with more experience can build upon my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All these components are based upon the RENDER event so no matter how many changes they go through (ex: x, y, width, etc ...) they are drawn only once per frame. But to get the RENDER event to trigger for each component a stage.invalidate() must be called and parsed on a per component basis. All the component invalidate methods allow you to force a redrawing of the component by skying the RENDER event step or in other cases by starting the RENDER event workflow.